# How to detect that a user has been muted in voice chat, and automatically unmute them with discord py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I don't have permissions on a server for muting/unmuting but my bot does. Moderators sometimes mute me "for fun" so I want to make my bot detect that I am muted (or have been muted) and unmute me.

I already have a bot which does many things and has several commands so I am pretty comfortable with bots in general, I just can't find precisely how to do what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Wrote an example of an event that will do what you want.

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if member.id == YOUR_ID_HERE:
        if after.mute:
            await member.edit(mute=False)
```