# Is there a way to detect if a member is speaking when the bot is connected to the Voice Channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

Is there a way to detect if a member is speaking when the bot is connected to the Voice Channel?

I couldn't find anything in the docs, so I'm guessing not, but maybe I'm stupid.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Do these help?: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.on_voice_state_update, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273587/how-to-detect-that-a-user-has-been-muted-in-voice-chat-and-automatically-unmute and https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.members

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect that a user has been muted in voice chat, and automatically unmute them with discord py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273587/how-to-detect-that-a-user-has-been-muted-in-voice-chat-and-automatically-unmute)

Comment: not really.. i want to detect the green light showing up when someone is talking not if the member is muted

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to detect if there's *a sound* coming from the member? In that case, check if these work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350976/discord-receive-audio/70987539#70987539, https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceProtocol.on_voice_state_update and https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.voice.

Comment: I also want to make a voice assistant. Receiving the audio is not the problem, but the logic is. I want to toggle my "start_recording"  func, when detecting voice (the green border) of someone in the channel. And I want to toggle "stop_recording" when there is silence for a given amount of time to trigger the callback function and process the received audio. But then I want to be able to receive audio without using a command again but for that i need to detect the "green border"

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it unless you're running the bot's code on your *own* PC. Then, you can probably use some AI to detect the "green border". Let's go step-by-step. Also, the other way I'm suggesting is to detect *sound* instead of the green border (the green border only appears when there's 'sound' from the member, not when they're just 'unmuted'), using the "`start_record()`" function. It's easier than graphic AI. I'm not familiar with converting audio either, but copy-pasting and modifying the function is worth a try.

Comment: You would probably need to continuously monitor the output of the channel (see the previously mentioned links, and you'll have to encode it in some codec somehow) and quit out of it when there's no sound coming out. What do you have so far? However, from my quick look at the docs and the source code, there's no way in discordpy to listen to the voice channel.

Comment: See [this issue on github](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1094)

Comment: @davelopment, please read my comment and Eric Jin's: I'm suggesting you (continuously) detect if there's sound input from the member using the function and if they're speaking, then run your function (to handle what happens if they're speaking and if not). Maybe you can put this in a while loop, so if they're not speaking, you can just continue, and when they're speaking, you can break the loop. Or, you can have a loop in a loop.

Comment: So py-cord(A fork of discord.py) allows it. This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350976/discord-receive-audio/70987539#70987539

Just make sure to install py-cord

`pip install py-cord`

Comment: @davelopment, yes, exactly. (so you don't need to check for the green border, as this is an alternative)

Comment: Okay.. but how would I approach getting the decoded audio from the WaveSink without cancelling the decoder?

Comment: @davelopment, what do you mean by *cancelling the decoder*?

Comment: the problem lies in line 806, voice_client.py: the socket becomes unreadable but doesn't return an error. Whats a possible cause for that?